# UILabel Not Resizing to UIButton Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uilabel

In my app, I have a subclassed UIButton.  It has 3 labels that I initialize like so:

```
self.firstLine = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, button.bounds.size.width, 35)];
    self.firstLine.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

In the XIB, I use AutoLayout like this, where in iPhone 7 Plus it would have width of 198.

[image]

I run it on 7 Plus and it looks fine and console shows width of 198.  I then run it on a 7, and console STILL shows width of 198, even though the button is obviously thinner.  What am I doing wrong?

iPhone 7 Plus

[image]

iPhone 7

[image]

Comment: are you using any leading space for labels?

Comment: Label width or button width is 198?

Comment: Frame of objects are constant until viewDidLayoutSubviews are called. So if you log it in viewDidload, then your value will always be same. Try to log it in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: @Poles The UILabels are made completely programmatically without any constraints set.  They just get set like how I show in the top bit of my code.  Here is how it all kind of looks for the button subclass `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        
        [self makeButtonShiny:self withBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)makeButtonShiny:(GlossyButton*)button withBackgroundColor:(UIColor*)backgroundColor {`

Comment: @GeneCode When I run the log in viewDidLayoutSubviews, it gets called twice.  Once with the width at 198 (7 Plus size), and again at 159 (7 size), and I am running it in Simulator for iPhone 7.

Comment: @GeneCode Here's the weird part...I have this built using XIB in IB.  The width of the button itself WILL change no matter which device is being used, exactly how I want it to.  However, the button reads its own width and sets the labels to the width of whatever the last Device I viewed it as in Interface Builder

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called many times and that is normal. It is called whenever the views needed to be resized by iOS (for eg, when scroll table, changing orientation etc).